# Logical equivalence versus definitional equality

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

From a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586580/transforming-fol-sentences)  it was confirmed that the equivalence:

$\forall x \forall y \bullet Overlap(x,y)  \equiv (\exists z Part(z,y) \land Part(z,x)) \ $ (1)

could be transformed into the pair of implications:

$\forall x \forall y : (Overlap(x,y) \Rightarrow (\exists z : (Part(z,x) \land  Part(z,y)))) \ $ (1a)

$\forall x \forall y : ((\exists z : Part(z,x) \land  Part(z,y)) \Rightarrow Overlap(x,y)) \ $ (1b)

Is this transformation still valid if the sentence is *definitional* using definitional equality?

$\forall x \forall y \bullet Overlap(x,y) \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} (\exists z Part(z,y) \land Part(z,x))\ $ (2)

Comment: YES. In [FOL the "expansion" of a language through the definition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/#LogDef) of e.g. a new predicate $\phi$ can be managed adding as an axiom, the universal closure of the bi-conditional $ϕ(x_1,…,x_n) ↔ \mathcal A(x_1,…,x_n)$.

Comment: There are two "equivalent" approaches in place : *(i)* expanding the object language adding the axiom (with bi-conditional); *(ii)* introduce the definitional equality in the meta-language.